# T-SQL: Efficient way to add up column values

Tags: sql, t-sql, sum, ssms, ssms-2016

Now I'm sure this has been asked and superbly been answered on here. However, I am unable to find the answer since it touches many keywords.
I basically want to replace a table of the form:

```
Type   amount   param   note
7      2        str1    NULL
42     12       str2    NULL
128    7        str3    samplenote
42     12       NULL    NULL
101    4        str4    NULL
42     12       NULL    NULL
7      1        str1    samplenote
128    2        str5    NULL
```

with a table like:

```
Type   amount   param   note
7      3        str1    combined
42     36       NULL    combined
128    9        NULL    combined
101    4        str4    combined
```

In words, I seek to sum up the amount parameter based on its type while declaring param = NULL for all "unclear" fields. (param should be NULL when the param values of combined Types have more than one different content; else, param should have the original content.)

With my python background, I tackled this task with a for loop approach, iterating through the types, adding a new row for every type with summed up amount and note = 'combined', to then delete the remaining rows (see below). There has to be a more efficient way with some JOIN statement I'm sure. But how would that look like?

FYI, this is the solution I am working on (not functioning yet!):

```
/*** dbo.sourcetable holds all possible Type values ***/
CREATE PROCEDURE [sumup]

AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @i int = (SELECT TOP (1) Type FROM [dbo].[sourcetable] ORDER BY Type)
DECLARE @MaxType int = (SELECT TOP (1) Type FROM [dbo].[sourcetable] ORDER BY Type DESC)

DECLARE @sum int

BEGIN TRY
    WHILE @i <= @MaxType
    BEGIN
        IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [dbo].[worktable] WHERE Type = @i)
        BEGIN
            SET @sum = (SELECT SUM(amount) FROM [dbo].[worktable] WHERE Type = @i)

            BEGIN
                WITH cte AS (SELECT * FROM [dbo].[worktable] WHERE Type = @i)
                INSERT INTO [dbo].[worktable]
                    ([Type]
                    ,[amount]
                    ,[param]
                    ,[note]
                SELECT
                     cte.Type
                    ,@sum
                    ,cte.param
                    ,'combined'
                FROM cte
            END

            DELETE FROM [dbo].[worktable] WHERE Type = @i AND ISNULL([note],'') <> 'combined'

        END
        SET @i = @i + 1
    END

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH 

    -- some errorlogging code

END CATCH

END

GO
```

Comment: What are the rules for calculating `param`?  What does "unclear" mean?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I added a sentence to explain what I meant by "unclear" here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved with a single `select` statement.

If you require your `combined` flag to only apply to where more than one row has been combined, add another `case` expression checking the result of either a `count(1)` for rows combined or `count(distinct param)` for unique `param` values combined:

```
declare @t as table(type int, amount int, param varchar(15), note varchar(15));
insert into @t values (7,2,'str1',NULL),(42,12,'str2',NULL),(128,7,'str3','samplenote'),(42,12,NULL,NULL),(101,4,'str4',NULL),(42,12,NULL,NULL),(7,1,'str1','samplenote'),(128,2,'str5',NULL);

select type
      ,sum(amount) as amount
      ,case when count(distinct isnull(param,'')) = 1
            then max(param)
            else null
            end as param
      ,'combined' as note
from @t
group by type
order by type;
```

Output:

```
+------+--------+-------+----------+
| type | amount | param |   note   |
+------+--------+-------+----------+
|    7 |      3 | str1  | combined |
|   42 |     36 | NULL  | combined |
|  101 |      4 | str4  | combined |
|  128 |      9 | NULL  | combined |
+------+--------+-------+----------+
```

Comment: dave you're perf.

Comment: No, *you're* perf @MichelleTurner

Answer (score 0):

I am doing this way from keyboard, but this may work or be close to what you want

```
Select type , amount , iif( dc=1,p,null) param, 'combined' note
from
(
   Select type, sum(amount) amount, 
          count(distinct Param) dc,max(Param) p
   From ....
   Group by type
) x
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution:

```
declare @tbl as table (
    type int
    ,amount int
    ,param varchar(15)
    ,note varchar(15)
)

insert into @tbl values (7,2,'str1',NULL)
insert into @tbl values (42,12,'str2',NULL)
insert into @tbl values (128,7,'str3','samplenote')
insert into @tbl values (42,12,NULL,NULL)
insert into @tbl values (101,4,'str4',NULL)
insert into @tbl values (42,12,NULL,NULL)
insert into @tbl values (7,1,'str1','samplenote')
insert into @tbl values (128,2,'str5',NULL)

;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT
        type
        ,SUM(AMOUNT) AS amount
        ,COUNT(DISTINCT ISNULL(param, 'dummy value')) AS ParamNo
        ,MAX(Param) AS Param
    FROM @tbl
    GROUP BY type
) SELECT
    type
    ,amount
    ,CASE WHEN ParamNo = 1 THEN Param ELSE NULL END AS Param
    ,'combined' AS note
FROM CTE
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
Select Type, sum(amount) as amount, count(distinct param)
, case when count(distinct param) = 1  then max(param) end as param,  
'Combined' as note
From 
mytable
Group By Type
```